# Regex select lines that contain more n occurence of a character

Tags: regex

Data:

```
hello 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
hello 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
hello 1 2 3 4 5 
hello 1 2 3 4 5
```

I know that `[ ]{n,}` works only for preceding characters only.

Comment: what are you asking exactly?

Comment: @melwil I want to select lines that contain seven or more spaces.

Comment: Regexes are for matching patterns. There may be a way to do this, but it's easier to write a simple script to count characters (and it will work a way faster).

Comment: @meiryo I agree with o2genum, you may use a built in function for example in php you could use [substr_count()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr-count.php).

Answer (score 2):

You could use something like:

```
(?: [^ ]*){n}
```

Would match a `space` followed by zero or more `non-space` characters **n** times.
You don't really need to check for *more* than n, because if it contains **n+1** spaces then it must contain **n**.

If you want to count all whitespace characters you'd need:

```
(?:\s\S*){n}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of just matching the space, you should also match the characters in between:

```
(\s\w*){n,}
```

This matches a space, folowed by zero or more 'word' characters, for n or more times.